# How is an argument delivered across closure and function?

Tags: rust, closures

I am reading [the closure examples in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html). For the following example code:

```
fn factory() -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    let num = 5;

    Box::new(move |x| x + num)
}

fn main() {
    let f = factory();
    let answer = f(1);
    assert_eq!(6, answer);
}
```

The factory is a function that takes 0 argument, but when binding `factory()` to `f`, why can `f(1)` deliver an argument of 1 into the factory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't.  You may have the wrong mental model for how closures work.

A closure is just a syntactic short-hand for a function with an extra initial argument that captures values from the defining environment.  We can rewrite your example into something which is *logically* equivalent:

```
fn factory() -> Box<Closure> {
    let num = 5;

    Box::new(Closure { num: num })
}

struct Closure {
    num: i32,
}

impl Closure {
    pub fn invoke(&self, x: i32) -> i32 {
        x + self.num
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = factory();
    let answer = f.invoke(1);
    assert_eq!(6, answer);
}
```

Note how `num` gets captured *into* the "closure" at the point the "closure" is constructed.  The body of the closure accesses this via `self` (which is magic'ed away for real closures).

The only differences between *this* and your original code are that:

1. The `Closure` type exists, but is *anonymous*.  That is, you cannot name the type directly, and thus you have to use `Fn(i32) -> i32` in the return type.
2. Because of the above, we return a boxed concrete type, rather than a boxed trait object.  In terms of how the "closure" is used, this doesn't really matter much to us.  The reason we can't return `Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>` is because...
3. We don't implement `Fn`.  This cannot be done in stable code yet.  If we *could*, it would be almost identical to the `invoke` method.
4. We define the body of the "closure" outside of the `factory` function.  However, this is just a syntactic difference: the body of a closure is no more "part" of the execution of your `factory` than the body of `invoke` is "part" of the execution of *this* `factory`.

So hopefully you can see that execution does *not* return to the `factory` function: it goes into a different function that just happens to be *defined* within `factory` for the sake of convenience.

Comment: This is super helpful! Thanks.